# Как программно нажать на SignOut используя JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как программно нажать на SignOut используя JavaScript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот весь HTML этого элемента

```
<td nowrap="" id="mx57_0" align="middle" valign="top" style="vertical-align:top;">

<div nowrap="" needsrefresh="false" vis="true" id="mx56_compHolder" class="bc" style="display:inline;">

<span align="middle" ctype="label" id="mx56" tabindex="0" targetid="mx56" mxevent="click" accesskey="S" class="text powerwhite  " style="display:block;;cursor:pointer;;;" title="Sign Out ALT+S ">

<img id="mx56_image" src="../webclient/skins/tivoli09/images/btn_signout.gif" class="pwimg" border="0" alt="Sign Out ALT+S" style="vertical-align:top;margin:0px;margin-left:3px;margin-right:3px;">

<span class="text hl hlak">S</span>ign Out</span>

</div>

</td>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Ответ для Pavel Nazarian:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скрипт MouseDown=>

```
function label_(event) {
  event = (event) ? event : ((window.event) ? window.event : "");
  var nc = this.getAttribute("noclick");
  switch (event.type) {
    case "focus":
      setCurrentfocusId(event, this);
      break;
    case "mousedown":
      input_mousedown(event, this);
      break;
    case "mouseout":
      var ul = this.getAttribute("ul");
      if (nc != "1" && ul != "1")
        this.style.textDecoration = "";
      break;
    case "mouseover":
      var ul2 = this.getAttribute("ul");
      if (nc != "1" && ul2 != "1")
        this.style.textDecoration = "underline";
      break;
    case "keypress":
      if (!hasKeyCode(event, 'KEYCODE_ENTER')) {
        break;
      }
    case "mouseup":
      //cannot click on labels in FF so we use mouseup
      if (nc != "1") {
        var eventValue = this.getAttribute("ev");
        var mxevent = this.getAttribute("mxevent");
        if (!undef(mxevent)) {
          var targetid = this.getAttribute("targetid");
          setClickPosition(this, event);
          sendEvent(mxevent, targetid, eventValue);
          cancelEvent(event);
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Window.open(url) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Мне бы что то вроде ```document.querySelector('#mx56').click();```

Comment: @Shahkumar41 А что происходит когда вы запускаете `document.querySelector('#mx56').click();`?

Comment: @EzioMercer, в ответ получаю "undefined", странно то что нет а href-а, не понятно как происходит клик. может за счет свойтсво mxevent="click"?

Comment: @Shahkumar41 `document.querySelector('#mx56')` находит сам элемент?

Comment: @EzioMercer, да. я выше добавил еще один скриншот. пожалуйста посмотрите

Comment: А вы `click()` тоже в консоли разработчика вызываете?

Comment: Можете открыть страницу в firefox. Там в инспекторе HTML наглядно можно посмотреть какой event на каком элементе задействован.

Comment: @Pavel Nazarian, выше я добавил для вас скриншот. пожалуйста посмотрите

Comment: @Shahkumar41 на event тыкнуть - что покажет?

Comment: @Pavel Nazarian, добавил еще один скриншот

Comment: @Pavel Nazarian, пожалуйста посмотрите, выше я добавил скрипт и скриншот